# Why does there appear to be more than 1 dmcl.ini file in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, cygwin, uac

Documentum uses a configuration file C:\Windows\dmcl.ini which I need to edit from time to time.  As the file is protected by UAC, I am editing it by running Notepad as Administrator.
However after editing the file, it does not appear to have changed:
1. The next Documentum process started continues to see the old version
2. The Cygwin 'cat' program displays the old version

Interestingly the Windows 'type' program displays the new version.  What is going on and how can I effectively edit this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6811355/unable-to-modify-ini-file-in-c-windows-directory

Once I located and removed the local mirror, everything was okay